# Refreshing Box API token from multiple servers

Tags: box-api

We are planning on migrating our Box v1 integration to v2.
Our integration implementation includes API calls accessing user box account and files from different servers at the same time.

With v2, and the introduction of refresh token, we would like to know whether multiple refresh token requests can be made concurrently from multiple servers over the same user account.

Moreover, and as a consequence of multiple refresh calls, we would also like to know whether it is possible to have more than one access key per user at any given time.

Thanks for the help
Assaf

Answer (score 0):

We recommend that you use some sort of coordination between your servers to manage auth tokens and refresh tokens.  While a user can have multiple access tokens for the same service, they will have to authenticate multiple times in order to get them.   You can't mint extra auth tokens off a single auth-token/refresh-token pair.

Here's what we recommend.

Create a pair of encrypted columns in your database to store the auth token, the refresh token, a datetime for "token_expires", and a flag for "token_refresh_in_progress".  Identify it by userID.

Write your code so that when you are about to make a call, if you are close (say, within a minute) of the token-expires datetime, instead of making your call, you check to see if the refresh-flag has been set, or if there's already a new token pair.   If the flag hasn't been by some other server in the cluster, set the flag that you are doing the refresh.  Make the refresh-grant call, and update the database with the new pair, and of course reset the flag.